# Preseed web/PHP front end

Tags: networking, installation, web, preseed

Has anyone come across a front-end (web based PHP preferably) for generating preseed files for automated server installs? Seems like the backend config changes occasionally so I'm sure keeping it up to date is a pain. Even if just the expert_recipe section, that would be a huge help.

Comment: Is preseed still relevant? https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall  - But indeed automated installation recipes seem to need adjusting for every major release